# function template with Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I write pull function to link (read -> through ... -> sink)

```
template<typename T>
auto pull(T &&stream) {
    return std::forward<T>(stream);
}

// return void/read
// read -> sink
// read -> through
template<typename R, typename S>
auto pull(R &&read, S &sink) {
    return sink(std::forward<R>(read));
}

// return read
// read -> through -> ...
template<typename R, typename T, typename... Ts>
auto pull(R &&read, T &through, Ts &&... args) {
    return pull(through(std::forward<R>(read)), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

read function, like this, provide a vector:

```
template<typename T>
auto values(T &begin, T &end) {
    return [&](bool abort, auto cb) {

        if (end != begin) {
            cb(false, *begin++);
        } else {
            cb(true, *begin);
        }
    };
}
```

through function, like this:

```
template<typename T, typename M>
auto Map(M &&mapper) {

    return [&](auto &&read) {
        return [&](bool abort, auto cb) {
            read(abort, [&](bool end, T val) {
                if (end)
                    cb(true, val);
                else
                    cb(false, mapper(val));
            });
        };
    };
}
```

sink function like this:

```
template<typename T, typename R>
auto log(R &&read) {

    std::function<void(bool, T)> more = [&](bool done, T val) {
        if (!done) {
            cout << val << endl;
            read(false, more);
        }
    };

    read(false, more);
}
```

then in the main function:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> vec;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        vec.push_back(i);
    }
    auto begin = vec.begin();
    auto end = vec.end();

    auto vals = values(begin, end);
    auto mapper = [&](int val) { return val * 2; };
    auto timesTwo = Map<int>(mapper);
    auto newVals1 = pull(vals, timesTwo, timesTwo);
    auto newVals2 = pull(vals, timesTwo);
    auto logInt = [&](auto read) { log<int>(read); };

    //pull(newVals1, logInt); // Segmentation fault, how to correct `pull` function to make this run right
    pull(newVals2, logInt); // ok

    return 0;
}
```

`pull(newVals2, logInt);` work right,

but `pull(newVals1, logInt);` throw `Segmentation fault`;

I want to make `pull(newVals1, logInt);` work right.

I think, may be some bug in `pull` function, but i do not know where, who can help me?

[code example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f481b7e0e71fde9d)

Comment: Lambda that escapes their scope via return or with a std::function that capture everygting by reference is usually a red flag

Comment: There's definitely another problem that I haven't worked out yet, but one problem is that you're dereferencing the `end` iterator in the `else` clause in the lambda in `values`.

Comment: SegFault means you blew your memory! I got yelled at this earlier! but thats the real issue. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've worked out where this is going wrong. As a previous user commented, you need to be very cautious when capturing by reference in a lambda that escapes its scope.

Specifically, I believe the problem is inside the `Map` function, where the inner lambda captures the `read` argument by reference. This is fine if it's called with an lvalue argument with a scope that will outlive the lambda, as is the case in the single invocation case `pull(vals, timesTwo)` => `timesTwo(vals)`, but in the double invocation case `pull(vals, timesTwo, timesTwo)` => `timesTwo(timesTwo(vals))`, the argument being passed to the outer invocation of `timesTwo` is an rvalue, so that `read` reference object is immediately dangling.

An additional, unrelated problem: in the `values` function, the `else` clause in the lambda will dereference the end iterator. I don't believe you depend on its return value, and it seems to work as expected, but it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'm also not sure if it's intentional that `vals` is essentially consumed after a single use, since the `begin` iterator is capture by reference and incremented until it's equal to the `end`.

Comment: I think you are right, bug how to correct it, can you help me?

Comment: @langyu which of the three bugs I've identified are you asking about? Surely you can work out how to fix some of them yourself.

Comment: case `pull(vals, timesTwo, timesTwo) => timesTwo(timesTwo(vals))`, `read` reference object is immediately dangling -> I want fix this bug, but I do not know how to fix it, I have spend 3 days... can you help me?

Comment: @langyu make all of your lambda captures explicit (no `[&]` - list all the the variables you want to capture), carefully deciding which should be by reference and which by value. Particularly, `read` needs to be captured by value in that particular lambda to avoid this segfault, but there are others that only happen to work in the specific use case, but aren't generally guaranteed.